# Can't work out how to start() media playing from a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-button

Sorry for the true noob question, but I've got a mental block over it...
I have media player in a service and a fragment with a play button that I want to control the media player...
Here's the fragment class

```
class PlayerFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = PlayerFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: PlayerViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PlayerViewModel::class.java)
    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    Btn_playPause.setOnClickListener { MediaPlayer().start()}
}


}
```

and here's the service class

```
class MusicService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private var pause:Boolean = false
    inner class MusicServiceBinder : Binder()
    {
    fun getService() : MusicService
    {
        return this@MusicService // the outer 'this'
    }
}
override fun onBind(intent: Intent) : IBinder {

    return MusicServiceBinder()
}
val mediaFile =  File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/Music/Over_The_Horizon.mp3")
override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
    val player = MediaPlayer()
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    player.setDataSource(applicationContext, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile))
    mp?.start()
    player.prepareAsync()

}}
```

Any helps greatly appreciated!

Comment: Other way I can suggest is to achieve the functionality, you can also use the Local Broadcast Receiver. Just send the action from the fragment and receive it in Service.

Answer (score 0):

Here I can suggest you the simple way to get control from the fragment by using Local Broadcast Receiver.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("Play"));//Here is Play as an action.
```

By sending this action from fragment and by registering intent-filter with "Play" action in your service will receive this intent and perform action accordingly.